# How to add 4 elements (objects) in array to localstorage, react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I want to add 4 objects the same as in array which should count. How to do so that in localstorage I will have 4 objects with the same properties?

```
componentDidMount(){
    const productData = [
        {
            productImg: JSON.parse(this.props.data.getProduct.mediaUrl).images[0],
            productPrice: this.props.data.getProduct.minimalPrice,
            productName: this.props.data.getProduct.name,
            productOID: this.props.data.getProduct.oid
        }
    ]

localStorage.setItem('looked-recently', JSON.stringify(productData))
}
```

Comment: Please explain more if you can

Comment: if you have multiple products then you better push new product objects in productData array and rest you are doing fine. On getting data from localstorage just parse and map on product data object. 
if you wanna add keys to product details then change structure lil bit.

`productData = [{product1:{info: 1}, product2: {info:2} }]`

Comment: if your scope of question is more then ping me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {

  const productData = {
    productImg: JSON.parse(this.props.data.getProduct.mediaUrl).images[0],
    productPrice: this.props.data.getProduct.minimalPrice,
    productName: this.props.data.getProduct.name,
    productOID: this.props.data.getProduct.oid
  }

  localStorage.setItem('looked-recently', JSON.stringify([
    productData,
    productData,
    productData,
    productData
  ]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple products then you better push new product objects in productData array and rest you are doing fine. On getting data from localstorage just parse and map on product data object. if you wanna add keys to product details then change structure lil bit.

```
productData = [{product1:{info: 1}, product2: {info:2} }]
```

If you have any query ping me will update ans.
Thanks